# Mysql hierarchical data question. Read in the description

Tags: mysql, database

I know there are many questions about hierarchical data but what I want is as below. So
I have a table like this

| id | name | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | income | 0 |
| 2 | expenses | 0 |
| 3 | assets | 0 |
| 4 | liabilities | 0 |
| 5 | shipping_related | 2 |
| 6 | direct_expense | 2 |
| 7 | direct_income | 1 |
| 8 | indirect_income | 1 |
| 9 | income_group_1 | 7 |
| 10 | income_group_2 | 7 |
| 11 | expense_group_1 | 5 |
| 12 | expense_group_2 | 6 |

I have many other data in this table. I am just trying to show what I want. I want to get all the subgroups whose `group_id` is either `1(income)` or `2(expenses)`. I found one solution for this but, it only works for one of them.

[Link to Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

In this you can see in the first answer, it is passing `19`, I need a query like this with maybe `in` condition.

EDIT: In MYSQL. Sorry forgot to mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the queries (given in the post you mentioned) work to solve your problem, you have to make a small change as given below:

**For MySQL 8+**: In where clause use `IN` instead of `=` and give any number of values you want desired result for.

```
with recursive cte (id, name, group_id) as (
  select     id,
             name,
             group_id
  from       Table1
  where      group_id IN (1,2)
  union all
  select     p.id,
             p.name,
             p.group_id
  from       Table1 p
  inner join cte
          on p.group_id = cte.id
)
select * from cte;
```

Link for Demo: [DB_Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3UXQwSt9kAC7WTJ26Y3Fkb/0)

**For MySQL 5.x**: In `select @pv` you have to provide list of ids for which you want the desired result like given below:

```
select  id,
        name,
        group_id 
from    (select * from Table1
         order by group_id, id) products_sorted,
        (select @pv := "1,2") initialisation
where   find_in_set(group_id, @pv)
and     length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', id))
```

Link for Demo: [SQL_Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f82779/1)

Comment: I need id 1(income) and 2(expenses) also. Is there any way? Like inclusive query

Comment: Ya there is a way. You have to replace "where group_id IN (1,2)" with "where id IN (1,2)" for MySQL 8 + and for MySQL 5.x add "or id in(1,2)" in the end of the query.

Comment: Thanks man. Can you also upvote question, cause I'm just starting out as stack user. It would help a lot.